# Extracting cell values from excel spreadsheets

Tags: bash

I am trying to extract values from Excel spreadsheet cells. The spreadsheet called `file.xls`. I used the code below (I am trying to use for loop because I have a sort of folders inside every folder I have the same spreadsheet `file.xls`)

```
#!/bin/bash
in=/a/b/c
for i in $(cat $in/list.txt); do
echo -n "$i "
sed -n '1p;d' ${in}/${i}/file.xls;
done > file.xls
sed 's/  */,/g' file.xls > fie.csv
```

The output file contains weird characters.
Any advices to make this code more efficient?

Comment: Are you trying to access the contents of a binary Excel file in bash? If so, that's bound to fail.

Comment: Better try `xls2csv` from `catdoc` package.

Comment: @dhag. Thanks! you are right I am trying to do so. Any suggestion?

Comment: Save your file with Excel as csv file.

Comment: @Costas. Thanks! This is cool! I will try it

Comment: @Cyrus. Thanks! My problem is that I have a very long list of folders ( 465) inside every folder I have Excel spreadsheet I wanted to extract specific info in one of it's cells

Comment: You might want to use a language that can read excel files, for example there's a [Spreadsheet::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Simple) module available for perl.

Comment: please have a look for this [How to split an ODS spreadsheet file into csv files per sheet on the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1042624/283843) post on AU as one of the ways to first convert that into a plain-text then extract what you want to have.

Comment: `ssconvert -O 'separator=:: format=raw quoting-mode=never' -S x.ods  out%n.txt` is an awesome solution!